# Return IEnumerable<T> or convert to List<T> immediately?

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I'm designing a class with several functions returning lists of objects. I noticed that debugging becomes easier when my `IEnumerable<T>` is converted to a `List<T>` since the objects can be viewed in the Watch window. However, I'm not sure if this is best practice when it comes to `IEnumerable`.

**Q: Which is better?**

```
public IEnumerable<MyData> GetData()
{
    return Foo();
}

public IEnumerable<MyData> GetData()
{
    return Foo().ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good practice - don't do work unless there are good reasons/required. So unless you have special reasons - just return `IEnumerable<MyData>` without calling ToList()/ToArray() on it.

Potential reasons:

- function promises to complete evaluation of potentially delayed enumeration
- you expect result to be enumerated multiple times

Comment: A small example for both (good) reasons would be very helpful for understanding.

Answer (score 2):

Better return `IEnumerable<..>` as more generic type. After *caller* can decide what to do with it.  In *your* case you return `IEnumerable<..>` in both cases, so there is *no any reason* run `ToLIst()`, just return `IEnumerable`

Comment: +0: Good advice... for aother question :) Note that return type is the same for both samples...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: will refrase the answer, to fit the question

Comment: +1 for edit, also I think "no any reason" is too strong (I have couple in my answer).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: the point is that from the *provided code perspective* I would leave decision on this to the *caller*.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on your requirements. The return type of a the method signature is also part of the contract of that method. A method returning an IEnumerable indicates a stream of values while a method returning a List (or more abstract, a Collection) returns a mutable collection of values.

I normally try to keep up with the following practices.

- Try and stream data in using an IEnumerable or IObservable when there is no fixed knowledge about the number of values or where loading all values would take a considerable amount of time/resources (e.g. query results).
- Use an array for fixed sets known in advance that should not be mutable.
- Use an ICollection for fixed sets known in advance that can be mutated.

Comment: In this case, the class sets up a database connection and lets you retrieve lists of data from the database. I'm still in doubt :)

Comment: I added some best practices. In your case i would go for the IEnumerable since retrieving data from a database will take some time and its unlikely that the amount if data is known in advance

Answer (score 1):

I'ts better to use a list of elements in case you are using a unit of work that will be disposed, because once its disposed you will not be able to get your elements after.

In all other cases its ok to return the generic **IEnumerable**, because it offers better flexibility.

In the end it all comes down to your requirements, note that IEnumnerable does not retrieve the elements at the exact moment of assignment to a variale but rather when enumerated.

Comment: In this case, the data is retrieved from a database (singleton) which itself is never disposed.

Comment: Im refering of course to cases when you use entity framework or another ORM and you implement a unit of work pattern.

Comment: +1 very important point. In normal situations return the do not call ToList. But when using something in an external scope that may change (connection, closure) you must ToList first.

Answer (score 1):

`IEnumerable<T>` is offering the caller a contract of a collection of T.  However, when you use `IList<T>` or `List<T>`, you are suggesting that they can add or remove elements directly (without going through any methods such as Add or Register you may have in your class implementation).  If your intent is simply to allow the caller to see the 'items', IEnumerable is the better contract.

Whilst it isn't 100%, I see IEnumerable return values as read-only collections.

Ease of debugging should be secondary to good design.  I would recommend that you simply unit-test your class rather than rely on being able to peek inside at runtime.  However, in most cases, the debugger shows the 'base' class as the first item.  So the IEnumerable's first item is the List you're actually using internally.  It only takes one more 'expand' to see the members!

Answer (score 0):

Returning IEnumerable lets the caller decide what to do with the results - either enumerate it or pass it on to something else without enumerating it at the current moment.
ToList() forces the data to be enumerated at this point, into a list which is then passed on to the caller.

Therefore - IEnumerable would most likely be the better of the two - however it can be easier to use ToList when debugging.

Comment: The Framework Design Guidelines advice to define the contract with the most specific type, so rather array than `IEnumerable`. The FGD advice against returning `List<T>`, since it is an internal type. Aray should be returned when you make a copy, `Collection<T>` when you keep a reference to that collection (so no copy). Of course this guidelines are for reusable frameworks, not for LOB applications.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple rule: return more concrette, accept more generic.

If your return value is really `IEnumerable<>` then return it as it is. But never do that:

```
public IEnumerable<MyData> GetData()
{
    return this.list; // list = new List<MyData>();
}
```

Code above limits caller without any need. It will be a list and caller anyway will be able to cast it to list and clear it for example.

Comment: `return more concrette, accept more generic.` aka `Accept the weakest, return the strongest.`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16934214/accept-the-weakest-return-the-strongest-but-why